@table-library/react-table-library afected by test using jes in a React app with vite
I have a react app that has a table made by @table-library/react-table-library, I have a test using jest called "use-table.test.tsx". The app is built using vite.
The problem is that when I eliminate the file "use-table.test.tsx", the table renders completely wrong, it seems like if the CSS were eliminated, because the data is there but completely overlap, but is not a problem inside the code of the test because if I eliminate all of the code inside the "use-table.test.tsx" file, the table renders correctly, even if I change the name of the test file, the table renders correctly. The table renders wrong only if I eliminate the file.
This is how the table looks like if I eliminate the "use-table.test.tsx" file:
enter image description here
Anybody has any idea how to solve this issue?
I already checked if there are imports or calls to the test inside the app code, but there is no import or call inside the app code to the "use-table.test.tsx".
